# Autocorrelation

Tags: autocorrelation

[image: joint pdf for autocorrelation]
[image: autocorrelation]

1. What is autocorrelation in real life? Any example?
2. How does  autocorrelation dependent on time difference? Here is Xt1 and Xt2 how comes \phi{tau}?

Comment: you need to learn about **ergodicity**.  a process is **ergodic** when probabilistic averages are the same as time averages.

Comment: it's nice if one can understand those things for sure because the concept of covariance stationarity becomes clearer.  But, as far as your  question, $\tau$ is the difference $(t_2 - t_1)$. The definition given there assumes that the process is covariance stationary which means that the correlation between observations spaced $\tau$ periods apart, only depends on $\tau$. For purposes of understanding, think of autocorrelation(tau) as the correlation coefficient of the  observations in the series that are $\tau$ periods apart.